# Travis CI - doesn't deploy build folder?

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm trying to deploy to GitHub pages with Travis CI but the `build` folder does not get committed on the branch. This seems like it would be resolved by adding `skip_cleanup: true` (I also tried `skip-cleanup: true`, however it still does not deploy the build folder.

Here is my `.travis.yml`. Any ideas on what might be causing this?

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 10
cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules
script:
  - npm run build
  - npm test
deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip_cleanup: true
  github-token: $GITHUB_TOKEN # Set in the settings page of your repository, as a secure variable
  keep-history: true
  on:
    branch: master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was that I needed to add the build folder to my `.gitignore` so that Travis was able to commit the files.